# Add Calculated Field To Pivot Table

Tags: excel, pivot-table, excel-2013, calculated-columns, calculated-field

I am attempting to add a calculated field to my pivot table that is attempts/success and show that as a percentage.  I followed these steps

> Click in pivot table
>   Press alt+jtjf
>   
> In the window that opens give it a name
>   
> add the formula to use

The formula I used was `=['Stolen Bases']/['Attempts']` but all that this did was sum the numbers.  So an example would be Bob's total would be 104 instead of 73.33%.  Below is an example of how I want my pivot table with calculated column to look.  Row Labels, Stolen Bases and Attempts all exist in the dataset but the Total does not that is a calculated field.

How can I add this calculated field column and have it accurately pull the percentage?
[image: Picture]

**EDIT**
One thing that may be causing the issue...the dataset is a sql server query and field setup has structure like so

```
playername
SBAttempts
Outcome
```

So my query to get stolen bases and attempts is

```
Select playername, 
case when outcome = 'SB' then COUNT(SBAttempts) else NULL end as "Stolen Bases"
case when outcome = 'OUT' then COUNT(SBAttempts) else NULL end As "Attempts"
From baseballstats
```

Which leaves my pivot table broken out like so:
Columns = outcome
Values = Count of SBAttempts
Rows = playername

Comment: The formula(without the brackets) works for me.

Comment: When I add it, it adds one row after Stolen Bases called Sum of Field1 and throws #DIV/0! errors in it, and adds a second one right after Attempts and throws #DIV/0! errors in it, then adds TOTAL to the end, but it is the SUM of 44+60 not 44/60 like I added to my formula

Comment: It works here, also (without the brackets).

Comment: @ScottCraner & Ron Rosenfeld - is your datasource a query or is the data source data that was manually typed into the sheet?  I can get it to work with data manually typed, but now with data from a query.